# Create specific exceptions for JQuery-UI tooltip behavior in a document

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a series of divs identifiable by class as dialog content templates. Among other things, the content divs have title attributes which are used by JQuery Dialog as the title of the dialog window, which is behavior I want. However, these titles are also used by tooltip, and that means that mousing over a part of the dialog that isn't any other control causes the dialog title to show as a tooltip. This is behavior I don't want.

How can I exclude the dialog content div, but not its children, from tooltip behavior? Currently, I'm enabling tooltips for the whole document as that's a one-liner. I can change that to only do it for buttons, but I have a lot of dynamically-created buttons (edit/delete buttons for table rows etc) that will have to be re-initialized with tooltips on each dialog reload, which I want to avoid if I can. The dialog content divs exist in the DOM from page load, so if there's a class I can apply or a method I can call on the class selector after enabling tooltips in general, that would be ideal.

**EDIT:** I found a working solution, possibly not an ideal one: Enable tooltips for the document, then disable them for the dialog content class, then when opening a dialog, re-enable them for all children of the dialog content classes (or the specific dialog being opened). It functions, but I'm probably asking JQuery to traverse the DOM way too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an ideal solution; when setting up tooltips for the whole document, set the `items` property to a `":not()"` selector:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ":not(.dialogContent)",
    ...
});
```